# Origin of Mareh Kohen tune

Tags: song-poetry, yom-kippur, music, musaf

Where did the [popular tune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_XbEjftIUrc) for the Yom Kippur piyyut, מראה כהן, come from?  Who wrote it?  When did it originate?  Where is it from?  Does the tune have a name other than "that marei kohen tune"?

Note I'm asking for the music, not the words of the piyyut.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was a little boy at home when my father Yigal Calek ny"v composed Mareh Cohen - there's a very interesting 'composer's inspiration' story to go with it too... Anyway, so yes, pretty much "at the source" ;)

Comment: Yoel Calek, thank you for this answer which is a primary source indeed! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: care to share the story on a public forum?  I'd be fascinated!

Comment: It's a catchy tune. But, I sometimes get annoyed when I see people almost dancing to it on Yom Kippur. I think there's a limit to the *simcha*.

Answer (score 11):

After a bit [more searching](http://songsatatable.org/preview.html), it looks like Yigal Calek of the London School of Jewish Song may be the original composer as late as [1971](http://djsa.dartmouth.edu/view_song.php?songId=22668).

Comment: I didn't log in to the second link and listen to the tune. Did you confirm that it is the same one?

Comment: @Menachem no, but the first calls it the "Yigal Calek" niggun.  I assumed he only did one version, but I could be wrong.

Comment: [This is a youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fks4YZa96qg) of a chazzan performing a medley of Yigal Calek tunes. At 4:07, he begins *Mareh Kohen*.