# Nezikin for Annoyances?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, torts-damages

Is there any concept of [Nezikin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damages_%28Jewish_law%29) for simple [annoyances](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18414/origin-of-mareh-kohen-tune#comment44500_18414) like in [secular nuisance law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuisance)?  What if said annoyances cause difficulty sleeping, studying, or working?

Answer (score 3):

A person who damages is obligated for five things: Tzaar (distress), ripui (healing), sheves (idleness), boshes (embarassment), and nezek (damage) ([CM 420:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40539&st=&pgnum=583)). However, we nowadays only obligate someone to sheves, ripui, and nezek ([1:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40538&st=&pgnum=6)), and some say only nezek (Rama there).

There is no question that annoying someone doesn't count for nezek or ripui. However, it may count for sheves, since you may be caused to waste time. So according to the Shulchan Aruch, you can take sheves, and according to the Rama you can take nothing.

However, it is nevertheless forbidden to annoy someone — ואהבת לרעך כמוך" "אל תונו איש את אחיו"

Comment: What about property issues, such as היזק ראייה?

Comment: I don't think that would count as an "annoyance;" it is more of a direct damage.

Comment: @DovF, in most of those cases, both parties are equally liable at the same time.

Comment: Hezek sheinah as well

Comment: Isn't that siman talking about wounding someone? Perhaps regular damages are different.

Comment: @DoubleAA That siman deals with damage that you do yourself. I didn't think the question was asking about someone's ox who annoys you.

Comment: @soandos say we have adjacent yards with a fence.  Because we can't see into each others yards, you feel private in your yard.  If I tear down the fence, we can both see each others yards.  If I make my house taller, so I can see over the fence into you yard, I am just as private in mine while you are not.

Answer (score 1):

There are a handful of actionable damages discussed in halacha that might be considered nuisance laws. The best place to look would be in Rambam hilchot sh'chenim.